# How to set default file opening application on Android 5?

Tags: default-applications, ebook-reader, epub

I have Aldiko Premium ebook reader application and it's a nice app for reading epub ebooks.

I can't set it to be the default application for reading epub ebooks stored as files on my micro SD card.

Every time I open a epub from File Commander, I am asked which app to choose to open the epub. I also have Moon Reader, so that's in the list as well as Google Book and an option to Install UB Reader.

When I go into settings for the Aldiko app, there is no button to Set Defaults.

So how can I not be prompted to choose the app each time I open and epub.

Android 5.0.2, Sony Compact Z1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Firelord for answering and for corroborating my findings. Appreciate your time certainly.

I'm not using FileCommander anymore for reasons as explained the underhanded approach to forcing users to use their reader.

I've found a solution I am happy with: I use Speed Software's Explorer Android App: nice app, nice design in combination with FBReader epub book reader. This combination works well, I can browse books I've organised in my own folder structure on my microSD card and click on them to open in FBReader by default. Also, I like it that FBReader doesn't import the books into its own library (i.e. make copies) that is not necessary, as I already have the file in my own folder organisation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android 5.0.2 as well and installed [File Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.fileman) to know how it provides options to choose a default app. It uses Android's default way. I don't have an E-book reader but the solution should work for your issue.

When you tap a file having multiple apps registered to open it and none set as default, you possibly would be shown options like:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]

You would've noticed that there are two options with low visibility *viz*.  "Just Once", "Always". Tap on your app entry once and choose "Always" to set as default option.

If you somehow cannot make it work like the way I mentioned, then you may consider [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) which would give you the option to choose default in the following way:

[image]

Comment: I get no "Just Once", "Always" links, only the apps to choose from. Not even in faint coloured text. Thank you for taking the time so far to help with an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I should've asked for a screenshot first than, my bad! Could you share a screenshot than?

Comment: When I try to screenshot, the "Open with" menu disappears, so I can't share it with you. It looks like yours but without the "Just Once", "Always" links.

Comment: OK, so are you open to any app based solution, like **ES File Explorer** I suggested?

Comment: Certainly, I'll take a look...

Comment: That works with a separate issue now. If I already had an ebook on the Aldiko 'bookshelf' then when I open that book through ES File Explorer, Aldiko says I already have it on my bookshelf with a button to dismiss. Well FFS can't Aldiko just ignore the fact that I have and let me still go through, perhaps with an advisory message. As For File Commander, I guess makers of File Commander, MobiSystems have disabled the Just Once, Always options to encourage people to install their UB Reader.

Comment: I see the issue now. You were right that File Commander has tweaked those options, and what's more, Aldiko doesn't accept the epub even  when I tried three different file managers, and made it default app for .epub file using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager). In that case, you would have to explicitly launch Aldiko to import the files by scanning the storage (pretty horrible coding design I would say).

Comment: +1 upvoted your answer and last comment - thanks for your time, I'll have a think and see what I want to do next and try to follow up here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25821/discussion-between-firelord-and-therobyouknow).